# My background image failed to load despite using local or external link

Tags: html, css

Here's html file:

```
<section>
    <div id="section1" class="container">
    </div>
</section>
```

Here's the css:

```
#section1{
    height: auto;
    margin-top: 0px;
    background-image: url('bg-1.jpg');
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I tried to replace the url with an external link (from google) but it still failed to load

Comment: When you say fail do you mean you've watched the attempt in the network tab? If so what error do you get? If not have you inspected the element? You need to provide details other than vague "failed to load" .

Comment: There could be something wrong with that file path/url. For example, my path looks like this `url(../images/add_non_us_safety_highlight.png)` in my CSS style. Like everyone else is saying check your developer tools in the browser, in the console, it will tell you the error and if it not cannot find it.

Answer (score 1):

Use your browser's **Developer Tools** to inspect and understand what might be happening. Maybe the element is being drawn with zero hight, for example, or maybe the network connection failed. In Chrome, right click on the page and click **Inspect Element** and then navigate around various tabs (such as **Elements**, **Network**, **Console**, etc.), refresh the page, and keep looking at the information that the Developer Tools panel gives you. This will be the easiest and most reliable way to understand how your page is being rendered, how resources are being downloaded, and what the issues may be.

Other browsers (Safari, Edge, Firefox) also have similar **Developer Tools** panels that you can turn on and inspect your page. I'm most familiar with Chrome's tools and find them extremely useful for debugging my webpages.